# How to share permissions logic between frontend and Hasura and avoir repetitions

Tags: next.js, permissions, duplicates, hasura, casl

We are currently creating a permission system on a NextJS application linked to a DB in PostgreSQL via Hasura.
Our goal is to share the permissions logic between the front and backend without being dependent on a specific implementation (hasura in this case).
We are using CaslJS for the frontend (we are open to suggestions as the implementation of this library doesn't suit us much but using Can is cleaner than putting `session.user.role === "admin" && ....type === "..."` ) where we already have permissions in place.
We use Hasura for the backend and no permissions have been set up yet.

The goal is to be able to conditionally display components based on the permissions that users have.
We also need to be able to verify that these users can edit, delete or update certain rows in a table.
These validations are necessary from the front-end to display certain components, but also in the back-end because we do not want an API to be able to bypass the implementation.
How to share permissions in both places while writing the code only once and having to maintain two sources of truth.
We also like the DRY rule

1. The first solution we thought of was to make a script to rewrite the permissions written in CaslJS and import them into Hasura at each build or whatever.
2. The second solution is to do the opposite. From Hasura, we export to create the CaslJS permissions. This solution is not enviable because we want to remain Hasura agnostic in case we change.
3. The last solution is to ask the community for advice.

Do you recommend the first solution, do you have other recommendations for implementations?
How to avoid duplication of this logic between front-end permissions?

Comment: I'm not aware of any existing community efforts in this area yet. I think if its really important to you that Hasura could be swapped out later you should go with approach number 1.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. If anyone else want to help, you're welcome !!

Comment: I have a similar Stack, Next.js 13 + NextAuth.js + Hasura + Casl.JS, and I have exactly the same dilemma, in the end which method did you decide on? if you used the first method, what format did you use to create the roles and permissions in CASL?

Comment: Since we haven't found a good solution yet and there isn't a prod version yet, we're keeping the validation in the frontend with casl which does enough for th emoment. We'll handle this problem in the latest phases of development. Don't hesitate to share you results as well.